# Getting details of added place from Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

Right now I'm working on a project in which I need to use the Google Places API and I'm too novice in using the Google Places API. The scenario which I want to ask is that how can I get details of a place using place_id which I got in response of place add?

I have searched through all the places but most of them said that you have to use reference attribute in request parameters. So, can I get a solution of this?

I read this information from these lines in Google Places API docs:-

```
Place Add Responses

Place add responses are returned in the format indicated by the output flag within the request's URL path.

The API returns a status code, and if the request was successful the response includes the following properties for the new place:

    place_id: A unique identifier for a place. To retrieve information about the place, pass this identifier in the placeId field of a Places API request.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What results have you gotten that aren't what you expect?  Start here: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

Answer (score 0):

There is an entire library that someone has built for the Places API for development in java or android. Please see this link: https://github.com/windy1/google-places-api-java